# Get method for returning initials

Tags: java, tostring

I am writing a short Java script to where I have a name in String as a variable. I want to write get method to get initials and return them for later use. That method works well when printing out the initials, but not when wanting to return that value.

```
//method for getting initials of the name
public String getInitials() {
    String words[] = competitorName.split(" "); 
    for(String word : words) { 
        return word.charAt(0) + " "; 
    } 
}
```

It shows me that the method must return a result of type String but that should already be it. And does not work even when I am adding toString methods  (then it writes that it is already String)

Comment: Why do you return after the first word and ignore other words? Also, what should it return if `words` array is empty?

Comment: Your method is currently returning the first initial only. Consider concatenating them in the  `for`  loop, and return the final result atfter the loop .You need a default return value anyway, since `words` could be empty, and then you won't enter the loop .

Comment: You may want to avoid saying or writing “Java script.”  What you wrote is a Java program, not a script.  JavaScript is the name of completely different language, which has no relationship to Java beyond its name, so a term like “Java script” is likely to create confusion.

Comment: @VGR I fully understand you. It was just a clumsy sentence. Of course, I meant script in a language Java, I will try using the literal sentence "Java script:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it! Just use StringBuilder and return result

```
public String getInitials() {
    String words[] = competitorName.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String word : words) {
        builder.append(word.charAt(0));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```